# How to merge multiple JSON files and average values

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I try to merge different JSON files, which contain this kind of data:

```
#file1:
{
  "user1": {
    "server1": 7.2,
    "server2": 10.3
  },
  "user2": {
    "server1": 15
  }
}
```

```
#file2:
{
  "user1": {
    "server1": 8.5,
    "server3": 20.5
  },
  "user3": {
    "server1": 28
  }
}
```

And so on (12 per hour).

These data are a list of users with the servers usage in percentage, evolving every 5 min (user may dissapear and reappear depending of resources usage).

I am under Linux and I generate these files with different Shell tools like `jq`.

My goal is to **obtain a merged file every hour with the average load on all available data**, like that (just considering the 2 files above):

```
#result:
{
  "user1": {
    "server1": 7.85,
    "server2": 5.15,
    "server3": 10.25
  },
  "user2": {
    "server1": 7.5
  },
  "user3": {
    "server1": 14
  }
}
```

I try several queries with `reduce` command, but nothing works as expected.

Maybe the best approach should to parse every files, extract data and store user in different file and after merge all data?

Thank for your analyse and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for an arbitrary number of input files. It first divides each value by the number of input files, and then adds them all up retaining the keys:

```sh
jq -s '
  .[][][] /= length
  | reduce (.[] | to_entries[]) as $u ({};
      reduce ($u.value | to_entries[]) as $s (.;
        .[$u.key][$s.key] += $s.value
      )
    )
' file*
```

```json
{
  "user1": {
    "server1": 7.85,
    "server2": 5.15,
    "server3": 10.25
  },
  "user2": {
    "server1": 7.5
  },
  "user3": {
    "server1": 14
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-w5H6JtEB-)

---

The division may also be shifted into the addition by using a variable at the beginning instead:

```sh
jq -s '
  length as $c
  | reduce (.[] | to_entries[]) as $u ({};
      reduce ($u.value | to_entries[]) as $s (.;
        .[$u.key][$s.key] += $s.value / $c
      )
    )
' file*
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ErcOByZ_q2)

Comment: ug, I added a virtually identical solution to my answer, but it wasn't copied

Comment: @ancherh Note: You could also flip servers and users in the output to get the orthogonal distribution: `.[$s.key][$u.key] += ...`

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```sh
jq -n \
   --argjson d1 file1.json \
   --argjson d2 file2.json \
'
   $d1 * $d2 |
   with_entries(
      .key as $user |
      .value = (
         with_entries(
            .key as $server |
            .value | ( $d1[ $user ][ $server ] + $d2[ $user ][ $server ] ) / 2
         )
      )
   )
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_h-AgRJlUR) on jqplay

`$d1 * $d2` creates the right structure, but with the wrong values. We then fix up the values.

---

Another approach:

```sh
jq -s '
   length as $n |
   reduce ( .[] | to_entries[] ) as $_ ( { };
      $_.key as $user |
      reduce ( $_.value | to_entries[] ) as $_ ( .;
         $_.key as $server |
         .[ $user ][ $server ] += $_.value / $n
      )
   )
' file1.json file2.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/doaxfjPmO3) on jqplay

This one works with more than two files!

Comment: Thanks for that, second approach is good but it need to specify the number of entries.

Comment: Re "*second approach is good but it need to specify the number of entries*", I don't know what you mean. What's a number of entries? You mean number of files??? No you don't; you just need to provide the file names on the command line. You can use a glob (`file*.json`) to get the list if you want. Also, it's virtually identical to the answer you accepted??? (The "second approach" currently in the answer might be different than the "second approach" you saw, but it was virtually identical and everything I said applies to that one too.)

Comment: Sorry, bad answer. Very similar to @pmf one.

Comment: Extremely. They only difference is that they chose `$u` for something that's not the user, and `$s` for something that's not the server, so I think mine's better :) (I'm not complaining that you accepted their answer. They were first.)

Comment: Anyway, thanks again for that. Different approach ensure different understanding, and people could choose the best ;)